# I over-fertilized my lawn

Tags: fertilizer

I misread the application instruction on the Scotts Fertilizer bag and set the rotary spreader to 7 3/4 instead of 3.  Is there anything I can do to prevent fertilizer burn?  I applied the fertilizer this afternoon so it hasn't had a chance to sink into the soil, yet.

Comment: Watering it in will help. I suppose an optimist might try using a vacuum cleaner if it's still bone dry, but that's not a very serious suggestion!.

Comment: Thanks alephzero - my wife wanted me to crawl around the yard with a bucket and a pair of tweezers and pick up each granule but hopefully she will let me use the vacuum !!!

Comment: if your lawn doesn't burn you're going to have grass that grows like crazy, but you'll want to keep fungi alive in your soil

Comment: Do not water it in.  This is more than twice as much fertilizer than called for on the Scott's package!  Your lawn will not grow like crazy UNLESS you haven't fertilized it at all all season and that is iffy.  Go get a gas powered blower and blow it out of your lawn.  Using the same blower blow the fertilizer and whatever debris into a pile.  Then finish by sweeping and scooping that pile up and disposing in your vegetation debris garbage or hopefully you have a pile of compost.  Layer this fertilizer into that pile and the fertilizer high in N will truly help decompose your compost faster.

Comment: What a sweet hubby!  I sure hope you aren't out there right now picking up the bits with tweezers!  Your wife is just trying to help you save yourself from a SIMPLE mistake.  This is how you learn to always measure, read the directions twice.  Grins, the vacuum is a great idea...a SHOP VAC not her Kirby!  Do both.

Comment: I will give you a tip; don't use Scott's or Ortho brands for lawn fertilizer. They are fast uptake, too fast, the grass grows too fast with this stuff.  The most amazing fertilizer product I've found in half a dog gone Century is Dr. Earth's Lawn Fertilizer!  A little more expensive, you use more per 1000 sq. ft. but you only need to use at most 3 applications not 4.  Extended release.  Takes longer to green which is a good thing but wow.  Get the fertilizer off the concrete with the blower.  Cut no shorter than 3".  Water deeply and don't water until you see your footprints on lawn.